# Xcode 10: Compilation stopped by errors in other files

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, ios12

When using Xcode 10 (Beta 1) and several Swift frameworks like [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka), the build fails with the following error:

> /path/to/Pods/Eureka/Source/Rows/Common/OptionsRow.swift:1:1: Compilation stopped by errors in other files

Unfortunately, the real error is hidden by now and cannot be uncovered. Anyone ran into that issue as well so far? We are still in the early Beta days of iOS 12 and Xcode 10, so this might be improved in future tooling versions.

Comment: This should be the syntax error if you will compile class manually then you can easily be resolved this issue. I was also getting the same problem and now resolved :)

Comment: @Cœur Technically it was one day :-) Thanks for the answer guys, and sorry to the down voters for wasting your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general error message meaning that there are other errors. The real error is **not** hidden. It's even written twice!

[image]

So you simply need to make your pod strictly compatible with Swift 4.1 to get ride of your problem. In your case, error message is:

> Overlapping accesses to 'action', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable

It was a **warning** with Xcode 9.x for the past **one year**, so you could have fixed it way before the release of Xcode 10.

Well, just do what the message suggests and it will work with Xcode 10:

```
let backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor ?? action.backgroundColor
action.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
let image = self.image ?? action.image
action.image = image
```

Or use **the fix made 22 days before your question** with https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/commit/b0f9adc13a780e76fae25bf00f9adc49726f0d95, by simply using the latest Eureka:

```
pod 'Eureka', :git => 'https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka.git', :branch => 'master'
```